# Plotly.js plot disappearing temporarily in Chrome on MacOS

Tags: plotly

I'm using plotly.js to render plots in a browser. When I scroll out of view of the plot, the plot seems to disappear. When I mouse over it again, it re-appears.

Is this a bug? Is there anything that I can do to prevent this from happening?

I've reproduced this behavior here (code below): https://jsfiddle.net/r6Ldo273/. If you scroll down and then back up, the plot disappears until you mouse over it again.

Edit: It appears that it may be browser dependent. I'm observing the strange behavior in Chrome, but am not able to reproduce it in Firefox or Safari. I am using Chrome version `54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)`

**Can anyone confirm they see the same behavior on MacOS when using Chrome?**

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5];
var y = [1,2,3,4,5];
var z = [1,2,3,4,5];

var data = {
  x: x,
  y: y,
  z: z,
  mode: 'markers',
  marker: {
    size: 5,
    line: {
      color: 'rgb(100,100,100)',
      width: 1
    }
  },
    type: 'scatter3d'
  };
   var layout = margin: { l:0, r:0, b: 0, t: 0 }
};

Plotly.newPlot('plot', [data], layout);
```

Comment: Hi. It could be helpful to see your code in a codepen or jsFiddle example or something like this. Therefore we can see the wrong behaviour. Maybe you can describe what I must do, do oberserve the wrong behaviour

Comment: @flipperweid I added a code sample

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome 54.0.2840.87 with Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for providing the snipped, that make it easier. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this too. I tried it with Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)

Comment: @flipperweid what OS? I'm running MacOS

Comment: Oh sorry, its Windows 10 too.

Comment: I also have this issue in chrome 63.0.3239.108 (64 bit) using ubuntu